# Simple topology questions

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have zero to none topology knowledge and need some clarification.

I have trouble understanding what the set of two topological spaces $A$ and $B$ mean. i.e. $[A,B]$. It's just that sometimes it seems to refer to a class of homotopies and I have trouble finding the definition of the expression.

I'm also having trouble showing that if $A$ is a contractible topological space $\implies[A,B]$ has a single element.

Comment: This notation denotes, in this context, the set of homotopy classes of maps between $A$ and $B$. So you have to show that if $A$ is contractible, then any two maps $A\to B$ are homotopic.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: If $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}$, then $A$ is contractible, while $[A,B]$ has two elements. Is it $B$ the one that is given as contractible? Or maybe is $B$ path connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two continuous maps $f,g:A\to B$ are homotopic if there is $H:A\times [0,1]\to B$ with $H(a,0)=f(a)$ and $H(a,1)=g(a)$ for all $a \in A$. Say that $f\sim g$ if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic. Let $[A,B]$ be the set of equivalence classes of continuous functions under this equivalence relation $\sim$.

Under the assumption that $A$ is contractible, showing that $[A,B]$ is a single means showing that any two continuous maps from $A$ to $B$ are homotopic. It will suffice to show that any continuous map $A\to B$ is homotopic to a constant map, provided $B$ is path-connected. Keeping notation as above, let $x \in A$ and assume that the identity $A\to A$ is homotopic to the constant map $A\to \{x\}$. Let $H_x$ be this homotopy. Given continuous $f:A\to B$, consider the constant map $f_x:A\to B$ given by $f_x(a)=f(x)$ for all $a$. Then $H:A\times [0,1]\to B$ given by $H(a,t)=f(H_x(a,t))$ satisfies $H(a,0)=f(H_x(a,0))=f(a)$ and $H(a,1)=f(H_x(a,1))=f(x)=f_x(a)$ for all $a$.

Comment: Thank you your answer helped me! Can I just ask what it means when you put the lower x index for example in $f(H_x(a,t))$?

Comment: It means nothing. It's a notation I chose.